How do I fix xtensor tile std::bad_array_new_length?
I want to implement np.tile(a[:,0], (len(b), 1)) in cpp xtensor and I got to the following line, with a xarray<float>(N,21) and b xarray<float>(M,21).
xt::xarray<float> res = xt::tile(
    xt::reshape_view(
        xt::view(a, xt::all(), 0), 
        {1, static_cast<int>(a.shape(0))}
    ), 
    {static_cast<int>(b.shape(0)),1}
);

However whenever I get to M>1 my process dies with std::bad_array_new_length. I verified the shapes of a and b and they are correct. Any idea what might be the problem?
As I didn't understand the problem I tried to extract it in the following helper file:
#include <xtensor/xarray.hpp>
#include <xtensor/xpad.hpp>
#include <xtensor/xio.hpp>
#include <xtensor/xrandom.hpp>
#include <xtensor/xview.hpp>

int main(){
    xt::xarray<float> a = xt::random::rand<float>({2,21});
    xt::xarray<float> b = xt::random::rand<float>({2,21});
    xt::xarray<float> res = xt::tile(
        xt::reshape_view(
            xt::view(a, xt::all(), 0), 
            {1, static_cast<int>(a.shape(0))}
        ), 
        {static_cast<int>(b.shape(0)),1}
    );
    std::cout << res << std::endl;
    return 0;
}

which gave me the expected output:
{{ 0.814724,  0.725839},
 { 0.814724,  0.725839}}

So I'm kinda lost now on how to fix this. Would appreciate some hints!

Can you create an [mre] of the failing code?

Hard as I'm depending a lot on other classes and external Inputs, but I'll try
